# logic while iterating a list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am new to java script and i need help with the logic of the code. I have a list which is read from csv. Now if in the csv Others is in the middle so it appears in the middle. I want that if others exist in the list it should be added in the end. $scope.disconnectRequestReason is the array I am dealing with. $scope.disconnectRequestParameters[i].paramLabel can have the value other.

```
 if($scope.disconnectRequestParameters[i].paramName == 'disconnectReason'){
     $scope.disconnectRequestReason[countReason] = $scope.disconnectRequestParameters[i].paramLabel;
     countReason++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use length($scope.disconnectRequestReason[]) to get the size of the array and use length-1 to assign values to the last element. If there are multiple "others" you would need to keep count of assignments. In this case you would use length - othersCount and increment othersCount accordingly.

Your code would more or less look like this

```
 if($scope.disconnectRequestParameters[i].paramName == 'disconnectReason'){

if($scope.disconnectRequestParameters[i].paramLabel == Others){
    $scope.disconnectRequestReason[length - othersCount] =    $scope.disconnectRequestParameters[i].paramLabel;
                othersCount++;
            } else{
$scope.disconnectRequestReason[countReason] = $scope.disconnectRequestParameters[i].paramLabel;
countReason++
}
```